# Redirecting all url's from a subfolder

Tags: url, redirect, web, prestashop, rewriting

i would like to redirect `www.abc.com/folder1/index.php` to `www.example.com/index.php`  what exactly happens is when i am in a sub folder like `www.website.com/subdirectory1/` and i click on the home button i get taken to `www.website.com/subdirectory1/index.php` instead of `www.website.com/index.php` so i need the rewrite rules to fix the issue.

i have already started rewriting the links one by one like

```
redirect /content/index.php http://www.example.com/index.php
```

but it takes a lot of time when new links are created and i cant be changing each one of them everytime. Thank you

edit: this only happens when friendly url is turned on.

Comment: Most likely you don’t need rewriting for this, but simply fix your “home button” link – make it relative to the domain root by prefixing it with a leading slash, `/`.

Comment: Thank you for your reply. i have tried doing everything with the home menu link but it simply reflects the changes inside the sub directory.

Answer (score 0):

I recommend you to take a read [on the official documentation](http://doc.prestashop.com/display/PS16/Setting+a+shop's+URL) it could save you many times.

Comment: Thanks but there was nothing in the documentation that could help resolve the issue.

Comment: Yes, if you set your shop url to the root, the generated .htaccess would do the work for you :)

Comment: The shop is installed in the root folder itself. the menu is LOF mega menu module.